# Installing Hyperledger Sawtooth

Tags: hyperledger-sawtooth

I am trying to install Hyperledger Sawtooth on ubuntu 16.04. While executing this instruction:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository 'deb http://repo.sawtooth.me/ubuntu/1.0/stable xenial universe'
```

I found this error:

```
** (mintSources.py:19571): WARNING **: Couldn't connect to accessibility bus: Failed to connect to socket /tmp/dbus-143bDHVFZH: Connexion refused
```

I have tested all possible solutions for such problem such as

https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=228894

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/at-spi2-core/+bug/1193236

, but I can't resolve the problem.

I would be very grateful if you could help me please.

Comment: This does not look like a Hyperledger Sawtooth issue. However, have you made sure the `add-apt-repository` command is available, by running `sudo apt install software-properties-common python-software-properties` beforehand?

Comment: This seems like an OS issue. You could try an alternative to using `add-apt-repository` is just adding the repo specs in `/etc/apt/sources.list` file. `echo 'deb http://repo.sawtooth.me/ubuntu/1.0/stable xenial universe' >> /etc/apt/sources.list` and then run `apt-get update`. You'll need root user privileges to run both commands.

Comment: Check this Link & Follow this simple instructions (updated): https://sawtooth.hyperledger.org/docs/core/releases/0.7/sysadmin_guide/installation_ubuntu.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just a warning and you can ignore it.Looks like it wanted to start a graphic display (probably over SSH) when it was not available.  A workaround to remove the warning is to add `export NO_AT_BRIDGE=1` to `~/.bashrc`

For details, see https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/sound-juicer/+bug/1526042

The installation instructions in an answer above are for the pre-release 0.7 version.  Here are the instructions for the 1.x release of Sawtooth:
https://sawtooth.hyperledger.org/docs/core/releases/latest/app_developers_guide/installing_sawtooth.html

Edit: Here's a brief summary of the package installation steps and initial setup:

`$ sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 8AA7AF1F1091A5FD
    $ sudo add-apt-repository 'deb http://repo.sawtooth.me/ubuntu/1.0/stable xenial universe'
    $ sudo apt-get update
    $ sudo apt-get install -y sawtooth
    $ sawtooth keygen
    $ sawset genesis
    $ sudo -u sawtooth sawadm genesis config-genesis.batch
    $ sudo sawadm keygen`

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.